# Iframe vertical scroll not working in iOS mobile

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iframe

I am trying to display a full screen website in Iframe, although vertical scrolling is not working on iOS mobile (tested on safari, chrome).

I'm using

```
<style>
iframe {
    border: 0; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100% 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    overflow:auto; 
}
</style>

<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
    <iframe src="http://www.neti.ee/">
</div>
```

Using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; is said to solve the problem, but it's not working for me. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; doesnt work on iframe. And dont use it, its not a [standard css rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling).
Use

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Comment: added overflow-y:scroll; instead of -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; and am still not able to scroll the website inside the iframe

Comment: Try <iframe scrolling="auto"> , but overflow-y, should works;

Comment: unfortunately still not working on iOS mobile device

Comment: Provide a link, as exemple.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll started to work when using:

```
 <style>
    iframe {
        overflow: scroll !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
    }

    div {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    body {
        margin:0;
    }
</style>

    <div>
        <iframe src="http://www.neti.ee">
    </div>
```